# Duplicate an icon in shiny actionButton

Tags: r, icons, shiny

I would like to add a `Font Awesome` 'child' icon twice in my actionButton in Shiny. The following app displays the child once:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("child","children", icon("child"))
)
server <- function(input, output) {
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I tried the obvious to no avail:

```
actionButton("child","children", icon(c("child","child")))
```

I must accept this is quite a niche question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the fact that you want the same icon twice. You just can't pass a vector of names into the `icon()` function.  If you look at the documentation of `icon()` it says it accepts the name of an icon, not a vector for multiple icons.

To do what you want, you can simply add multiple icons in the label. Something like this

```
actionButton("child", div(icon("child"), icon("child"), "children"))
```